# SSIS task hangs during validation phase at 66%

Tags: validation, ssis

I have a packages that drops foreign key constraints on 2 of the 3 connected tables in the destination database then, one by one copies the table data for each of the 3 tables from source to destination. Both connections, source and destination have DelayValidation property set to true. Constraints get dropped, first table gets populated then second table starts but always hangs at 66% validation. It first goes to 0%, then 33%, then 66% and just hangs there. Can anyone help me diagnose the issue?

P.S> also my SSIS project is set to Work Offline - otherwise VS just freezes

Comment: Try setting DelayValidation on the package level to true.

Comment: It is already set to true. It is in the question on line 3

Comment: Line 3 says "Both connections, source and destination".   I'm saying set it at the package level.    Meaning click somewhere in the Control Flow area to select the package, and then find the DelayValidation property for the package and set it to true.

Comment: Just did that and still the same result - starts Validating and gets stuck at 50%